# Defining OR in Ruby using Watir-or framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I am  using watir-or framework in order to deal with web objects. Below is my code:

```
require 'watir-or'
require 'watir' # Support all "watirs": firewatir, safariwatir and etc

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

repository = ObjectRepository::Repository.new("path to my xls file which i stored an id for each object and description to each one", browser)
repository.get("txt_UserName").click
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:30: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

[watir-or](http://rubygems.org/gems/watir-or)'s last release was in 2011. That is 3 years in human years, or 300 years in internet years. Since then, both [firewatir](http://rubygems.org/gems/firewatir) and [safariwatir](http://rubygems.org/gems/safariwatir) were deprecated in favor of [watir-webdriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver). I would suggest that you try a contemporary page object gem instead of watir-or, like [page-object](http://rubygems.org/gems/page-object).

Comment: can i implement an OR in excel sheet and interact with it using page object the same in watir-or ?